# Magento: Add Taxvat from customer to billingaddress

Tags: magento-1.7

I was wondering how the VAT number is being saved in the billing-address from a customer. I can't find it in the code and there is no solution to be found online. Hopefully someone can help me out.

Reason why I'm looking for this: Magento Core 1.7 provides the EU VAT service itself instead of installing 3th party extensions. But it looks @ the VAT number which is saved in the address instead of the VAT number from the customer. Unfortunately it's not possible to add the VAT number in the address you create in "my account" by default.

Big thanks for anyone who can help out!

Answer (score 0):

In the invoice PDF I use:

```
$taxvat = $order['customer_taxvat'];
```

And then echo that where you need it.

In the admin I suppose you can use {{order.customer_taxvat}}, but I haven't tested that yet.